# SQL : Skipping Record of table (Java / JPA / Criteria Implementation)

Tags: sql

We have a table with historical data : id, department, totalInsert, totalUpdates, createdTime

in which data is inserted every 1 hour.

[image]

based on above data we need to fetch data as per provided duration and interval.

**For Example :** 
Duration = 24 hours and Interval = 1 hour
then last 24 hours data should be fetched for every 1 hour interval. (24 records)

Duration = 24 hours and Interval = 4 hour
then last 24 hours data should be fetched for every 4 hour interval. (6 records)

Duration = 7 days and Interval = 1 day
then 7 days data should be fetched for every 1 entry per day. (7 records)

Duration = 21 days and Interval = 7 day
then 21 days data should be fetched for every 1 entry per week. (3 records)

[image]

So, can you help to have generic query for all above possible scenarios.
Don't want separate query for each input provided by user.

**Tried So Far :**

> SELECT *  FROM department_details  WHERE id IN ( SELECT MAX(id) FROM
>   department_details  WHERE department='Computer Technology' AND
>   ((date(createdDate) > '2019-01-09' AND date(createdDate) <=
>   '2019-01-10') OR          (date(createdDate) > '2019-01-15' AND
>   date(createdDate) <= '2019-01-16') OR           (date(createdDate) >
>   '2019-01-21' AND date(createdDate) <= '2019-01-22') OR
>   (date(createdDate) > '2019-01-27' AND date(createdDate) <=
>   '2019-01-28') OR           (date(createdDate) > '2019-02-02' AND
>   date(createdDate) <= '2019-02-03'))                GROUP BY
>   date(createdDate) ) ORDER BY createdDate;

Looking for Generic JPA Criteria solution

Comment: Show what you tried so far

Comment: When you say that 1 record per interval is it like a 
summarization of the data during that interval?

Comment: Are you looking for a SQL solution or a JPA/Criteria API solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've build an maven example. You have to store the `createdTime` as a `Long` (see `HistoricalData#createdTime`). In `App#getData` you can see the usage of the interval.

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>de.dbh.basis.legacy</groupId>
    <artifactId>JpaTest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.197</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="test" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:test;MVCC=1"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**HistoricalData.java** (Entity)

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

@Entity
@Getter @Setter
@ToString
public class HistoricalData implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String department;
    // The createdTime will be stored as a Long    
    private Long createdTime;

    public HistoricalData() {
    }

    public HistoricalData(int id, String department, Date createdTime) {
        this.id = id;
        this.department = department;
        this.createdTime = createdTime.getTime();
    }

    public Date getCreatedTime() {
        return new Date(createdTime);
    }

    public void setCreatedTime(Date createdTime){
        this.createdTime = (createdTime == null ? null : createdTime.getTime());
    }
}
```

**App.java** (the important part)

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Root;
import org.apache.commons.lang.time.DateUtils;

public class App {

    private static EntityManagerFactory emf;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Build the query
        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("test");
        // Persistence Preparation
        fillDatabase();

        // Define start and end date (must be a full hour)
        Calendar from = DateUtils.round(Calendar.getInstance(), Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        from.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, -4);
        Calendar to = Calendar.getInstance();
        // Define interval - One day in milliseconds (must be a multiple of one hour
        int interval = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

        // Do the query
        List<HistoricalData> data = getData(from, to, interval);
        System.out.println("DATA: "+data.size());
        for( HistoricalData item : data ){
            System.out.println(item);
        }
    }

    private static List<HistoricalData> getData(Calendar from, Calendar to, int interval){
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        CriteriaBuilder b = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<HistoricalData> q = b.createQuery(HistoricalData.class);
        Root r = q.from(HistoricalData.class);
        q.where(b.and(
                // search all data between 'from' till 'to' date
                b.greaterThanOrEqualTo(r.get("createdTime"), from.getTime().getTime()),
                b.lessThanOrEqualTo(r.get("createdTime"), to.getTime().getTime()),
                // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                //
                // Here we have your interval
                //
                // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                b.equal(b.mod(b.diff(r.get("createdTime"), from.getTime().getTime()), interval), 0)
        ));
        return em.createQuery(q).getResultList();
    }

    private static void fillDatabase(){
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        Calendar cal = DateUtils.round(Calendar.getInstance(), Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        // Insert Data into the database (8 weeks - every hour)
        for (int i = 0; i < 24*8; i++) {
            HistoricalData data = new HistoricalData(i, "Department " + i, cal.getTime());
            em.persist(data);
            cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, -1);
        }
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Here how we are skipping in between records?

Comment: @VaibhavSawant You are right. It was a misunderstanding. I've updated my exampe

Comment: In above example, createDate field is of type Date (SQL TimeStamp). So, it is giving error on b.diff (as it is expecting long)

Comment: Also, difference of createdTime and interval can't be always 0 because let's say we have createdDate= 26-Feb-2019 10:00:12 and fromDate = 25-Feb-2019 10:00:00. In this case let's say difference is 432423%10 = 3 (But, it doesn't mean that we need to skip this record)

Comment: The `createdTime` must be a `Long` (I wrote it at the begining of my answer). If you can not ensure, that the createdTime is always a full hour, you have to change the query from `b.equal(b.mod(...` to `b.lt(b.abs(b.mod(...` and check this against your tolerance (in your example <= 3000ms)

Comment: Used between and achieved same